# Convert http get call from angular 2 to newest version

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary

Im trying to make my new project in the newest avaliable angular version.

I had a previous project with the following code:

```
 return this.http.get("XXXX", {withCredentials: true}).map(e => {
      console.log(e.json());
        return false;
    }).catch(() => {
      console.log("???");
      return Observable.of(false);
    });
```

the above worked okay in my angular2 project, but when i try however to convert it to angular7(?) , i get the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/global.service.ts(54,29): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?
```

this is the piece of current code:

```
this.http.get(url).pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
```

i also tried to adjust the code to something like:

```
return this.http.get( url,this.options).pipe(map(DATA) =>  {

  console.log(data);
  return data;

  });
```

but cant seem to get any way further.

what is wrong with my code, and what do i need to do to make it work?

imports:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from "./../environments/environment";

import { Observable, Subject  } from "rxjs";
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the `HttpClientModule` in the `appModule`?

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpClient` in Angular 7 does not (natively) return a promise or something that one can use `map()` on. The return is an Observable and must be subscribed to or `pipe`'d through rxjs operators.

Your code should resemble this:

```
return this.http.get("XXXX")
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

In which `handleError` would be a class method.

In your component you would `subscribe` to the returned observable to get the data:

```
.subscribe(
      data => this.data = data /* do something with data */ , // success path
      error => this.error = error // error path
    );
```

As a side note, the observable from HttpClient can be turned into a promise if you desired.

Comment: Thanks! i believe the best approach is obserable and not promise?

Comment: me too :-). Glad to help.

Comment: hey , you have some time to chat privatly?

Comment: @maria Just saw this...not available now. You are welcome to look me up via Linked In and connect there.

Answer (score 0):

//  Example Get request

```
 import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


 const httpOptions = {

 headers: new HttpHeaders({

  'Content-Type':  'application/json',

  'Authorization':  'token'

 })};

 get_data (): Observable<any> {

     const Url = `${serviceurl}`;

     return this.http.get<any>(Url, httpOptions)

     .pipe(map(res => res))

     .catch(err => err);
  }
```

//  Example 2:

```
  get_data (): Observable<any> {

     const Url = `${serviceurl}`;

     return this.http.get<any>(Url)

     .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError('get_data'))
       );

  }
```